# How are Feral Ghoul attacks possible?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I was told by a friend that he was attacked by Ghouls in his Vault. I first thought it isn't quite true.
**But then, I saw this, while scrolling in the Statistics:**
[image: Feral Ghoul statistic]

*So, how are they possible? From which population and what is the rarity of them?*

***P.S.: I didn't saw anything on the Wikia or the Gampedia related to this.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feral Ghoul attacks like a Raider/Deathclaw attack.  They come up to your vault door, claw it open, and cause damage along with radiation damage.

They are not as deadly as Deathclaws, but are definitely worse than Raiders due to the radiation damage.

You can watch a Feral Ghoul attack here:

Comment: Those are probably maxed out dwellers defending at the vault door.  Your usual 1-3 E dwellers will take about half their health in rad damage.

Answer (score 2):

In a new update they have added Feral Ghoul Attacks.

While, surprisingly, I too have been unable to unearth any solid evidence of this on the internet, from experience; they happen randomly, just as the Raider, Radroach, Radscoprion, Molerat and Deathclaw attacks do.

Edit: Ghouls attacks are fast and deal large amount of Radiation damage to dwellers, but move quickly through rooms, similar to Deathclaw attacks

[image]

[image]